# Encryption in javascript

Tags: javascript, android, json, encryption

I am working on a mobile app (target: Android, iOS, Windows) - using corodova, ionic on Visual Studio 2015.

My Approach (Please let me know if this makes sense):

1. The app will store user's data in encrypted format in json object across the application flow.
2. When user submits final page, the data will be decrypted from json object and will be sent via service call( web api2) using post method over HTTPS.

For the first part, we are planning to do encryption using device specific key. The same key will be used to decrypt. I am worried that this should not put us on any potential risk. If so then is there any other approach to do the same? The data that user enters MUST NOT BE EASILY DECREPTABLE.

Thank you.

Comment: Why do u want to encrypt it on the client side?

Comment: If they have the users device and their password what is going to stop them from decrypting it anyway?

Comment: What you are doing is pointless.  If both the key and ciphertext are on the client side then there isn't much point.

Comment: Luke, brso05: Thank you for the input, but as I said, I wanted to make sure that this is good approach or not? Can you please remove the -1 for the newbie sake? :)

Answer (score 0):

> If so then is there any other approach to do the same?

Use [libsodium](https://download.libsodium.org/doc/bindings_for_other_languages/index.html) for public-key authenticated encryption. Store the public key in your app, use the secret key to decrypt on the server. You can use sealed boxes here.

> 1. The app will store user's data in encrypted format in json object across the application flow.
> 2. When user submits final page, the data will be decrypted from json object and will be sent via service call( web api2) using post method over HTTPS.

Why do you need to encrypt it across the application flow? [Read this](https://paragonie.com/blog/2016/03/client-authenticity-is-not-server-s-problem). You can't stop them from recovering plaintext from a device they own.

Comment: Ok, I understand, but this is a kind of offline data collection application. User (Agent) will put the device offline and collect data from fields. That's why we would like to encrypt data on client device.

Comment: If you need to be able to *decrypt* offline, rather than just *blindly encrypt* offline, an attacker can decrypt your data. Be prepared for that.

Comment: Ok, than what's the best alternative? The agent or attacker should not be allowed to see the data stored offline - that's what I am trying to achieve.

Comment: [Abandon all hope, ye who enter here](https://twitter.com/fredericjacobs/status/626703171839201280). [Hiding your white-box designs is not enough](https://eprint.iacr.org/2015/753). Etc.